# End of file expected.json line 21

Tags: json

Can someone correct my JSON code and tell me what I did wrong? When I try to use it, I get an error on line 21, and I don't know what to do.

This is my code:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "editor.linkedEditing": true,
    "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "files.autoSaveDelay": 1,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "firefox",
    "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "easy-icons",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Field Lights",
    "workbench.editorAssociations": [
        {
            "viewType": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb",
            "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
        }
    ],
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
    }
}
{
    "actionButtons": {
        "defaultColor": "white",
        "reloadButton": "Reload",
        "commands": [
            {
                "name" : "Build",
                "color": "white",
                "command": "idf.py build"
            },
            {
                "name" : "Run",
                "color": "white",
                "command": "idf.py flash -p COM1 -b 921600 monitor"
            }
        ]
    }, 
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1. You have a comma at the second last bracket.
2. It seems like you have 2 JSON objects as parents in the same file. I'm pretty sure that a JSON file only can have one parent/root that is either an object or an array.

This means that you will need to have two files instead of one.
One containing the first JSON object:

```json
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "editor.linkedEditing": true,
    "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "files.autoSaveDelay": 1,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "firefox",
    "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "easy-icons",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Field Lights",
    "workbench.editorAssociations": [
        {
            "viewType": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb",
            "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
        }
    ],
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
    }
}
```

And another containing the second JSON object:

```json
{
    "actionButtons": {
        "defaultColor": "white",
        "reloadButton": "Reload",
        "commands": [
            {
                "name" : "Build",
                "color": "white",
                "command": "idf.py build"
            },
            {
                "name" : "Run",
                "color": "white",
                "command": "idf.py flash -p COM1 -b 921600 monitor"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You could also have it in the same file, but wrapped in another root/parent object, like this:

```json
{
    "object1": {
        "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
        "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
        "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
        "editor.linkedEditing": true,
        "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
        "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
        "files.autoSaveDelay": 1,
        "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
        "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "firefox",
        "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
        "workbench.iconTheme": "easy-icons",
        "workbench.colorTheme": "Field Lights",
        "workbench.editorAssociations": [
            {
                "viewType": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb",
                "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
            }
        ],
        "[html]": {
            "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
        }
    },
    "object2": {
        "actionButtons": {
            "defaultColor": "white",
            "reloadButton": "Reload",
            "commands": [
                {
                    "name" : "Build",
                    "color": "white",
                    "command": "idf.py build"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Run",
                    "color": "white",
                    "command": "idf.py flash -p COM1 -b 921600 monitor"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Or do it as an array, like this:

```json
[
    {
        "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
        "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
        "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
        "editor.linkedEditing": true,
        "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
        "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
        "files.autoSaveDelay": 1,
        "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
        "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "firefox",
        "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
        "workbench.iconTheme": "easy-icons",
        "workbench.colorTheme": "Field Lights",
        "workbench.editorAssociations": [
            {
                "viewType": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb",
                "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
            }
        ],
        "[html]": {
            "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
        }
    },
    {
        "actionButtons": {
            "defaultColor": "white",
            "reloadButton": "Reload",
            "commands": [
                {
                    "name" : "Build",
                    "color": "white",
                    "command": "idf.py build"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Run",
                    "color": "white",
                    "command": "idf.py flash -p COM1 -b 921600 monitor"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you improve it for me?

Comment: @mita_maus070 I've updated my answer so that it contains some different solutions.